# PostegreSQL error: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « d »

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to enter html in a column

```
client.query("INSERT INTO public.articles( titre, html, tag) VALUES ( '"+[titre]+"', '"+[html]+"', '"+[tag]+"')");
```

After each insert I get an error

```
(node:18412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « d »
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\lou\Documents\nodejs\slood\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:241:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\lou\Documents\nodejs\slood\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:89:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\lou\Documents\nodejs\slood\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:41:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lou\Documents\nodejs\slood\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
(node:18412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I found the solution by converting to base 64

```
html = Buffer.from(html).toString('base64')
```

thanks